# I'm super new to all this Ethereum stuff. Can anyone suggest me a place to learn how it works?

Tags: dapp-development

I've been tasked with writing a blockchain-based application (probably written in JS) that can be used to certify documents. I've done some research into where I can get stuff hosted (Infura looks the best right now). Can anyone suggest me a place to learn all about Ethereum/blockchain? And where would I start with the creation of my project? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Disclosure: I am an instructor (instructor-led programs) and content creator: https://academy.b9lab.com/courses/course-v1:B9lab+DISCOVERY+2019/about

Comment: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/

Comment: Cryptozombies for learning Solidity/web3

Answer (score 0):

I just published The hitchhiker’s guide to Ethereum development. It provides a starting point for developers who’re keen to learn more about blockchain and development on top of Ethereum. The guide covers:

1. Blockchain foundations
2. Ethereum 101
3. Ethereum Development, Smart contracts & DApps
4. Advanced Topics, privacy, performance & permissioning
5. Next steps

https://wslyvh.com/ethereum-guide/

In terms of courses, I'd recommend:

- **[Blockchain Essentials](https://academy.b9lab.com/courses/course-v1:Blab+BEC-FREE+2018-08/about)**: An introduction for non-developers, B9lab Academy - a free introductory course that offers a high-level overview of blockchain technology for a non-technical audience. NOTE that if you’re a developer you can probably skip this, as this will all be covered in the developer course.
- **[Introduction to Ethereum for Developers](https://academy.b9lab.com/courses/B9lab/X16-0/2016/about)**, B9lab Academy - free Ethereum course gives you an overview of blockchain technology and covers the very basics of Ethereum. NOTE that the course is slightly outdated in terms of tools and ecosystem, but the basics and principles remain a good starting point.
- **[Crypto startup school](https://a16z.com/crypto-startup-school/)**, a16z - incredible insight from people like Brian Armstrong from Coinbase, Robert Leshner from Compound, and Sam Williams from Arweave among others.
- **[Blockchain and Money](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-s12-blockchain-and-money-fall-2018/)**, MIT - This course is for students wishing to explore blockchain technology’s potential use - by entrepreneurs & incumbents - to change the world of money and finance. Watch on Youtube

Or check out one of the following:

- [Cryptozombies](https://cryptozombies.io/) (highly recommended)
- [Ethernaut](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/)
- [ETH.build](https://eth.build/)